# read an string array as property name?

Tags: javascript

```
newDesign = {
    color: 'blue',
    shape: 'round'
}

oldDesign = {
    color: 'yellow',
    shape: 'triangle'
}
```

I want to compare this two design to see if their field is changed, so I write these:

```
fields = [ 'color', 'shape' ]
for (let field in fields) {
    if (oldDesign.field !== newDesign.field)
        console.log('changed')
}
```

However, looks like I can't read the value of fields by using oldDesign.field.

Is there a way to to this? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `for..in` to loop arrays [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504)

Comment: Use a `for` loop or `forEach` like this: `fields.forEach(field =>{ if (oldDesign[field] !== newDesign[field])
        console.log('changed') })`

Answer (score 0):

Use the bracket notation

```js
var newDesign = {
    color: 'blue',
    shape: 'round'
}

var oldDesign = {
    color: 'yellow',
    shape: 'triangle'
}

var fields = [ 'color', 'shape' ];
for (let field in fields) {
    if (oldDesign[fields[field]] != newDesign[fields[field]])
        console.log('changed')
}
```